# Getting width of div element in Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery, mobile, width, element, hidden

I understand that all elements are hidden in jquery mobile. But i need to get the value of the width of 'div' element in the very first main page loaded. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Please make your question clear with some code.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#your_div').width();  // you have also .outerWidth() and .innerWidth()

  // you can also try with

  $('#your_div:hidden').width();   

  // or

   $('#your_div:hidden').css('width');

});
```

#### According to comment

```
$('div.myClass:hidden').css('width'); // select div with class myClass and hidden also
```

You can also do following trick to get width of hidden div

```
$(".myClass").css({'position':'absolute','visibility':'hidden','display':'block'});

var optionHeight = $(".myClass").width();

$(".myClass").css({'position':'static','visibility':'visible','display':'none'});
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly. How do i select a more detailed say 'div element' with class "myClass" and hidden width?

Comment: @dewamonyet80 what do you mean by hidden width? check my update

Comment: It seems that when another div is inside of the of a div, the hidden width is always 0. So when i have <div data-role="page" id="page><div data-role="content" id="page_content"></div></div> -> $('#page_content:hidden').width() is always 0. Am i doing this right?

Comment: @dewamonyet80 I've updated my question and I think it'll resolve your problem

Comment: For some reason, the updated solutions gave 0px and 0. I dunno why though.

Comment: If i have <div data-role="page" id="page"><div data-role="content" id="page_content"></div></div>, tried $( '#page #page_content:hidden' ).width() or css( 'width' ) yield zero as well.